# nginx 301 redirect to incorrect vhost

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, proxy, vhosts

I'm having a 301 redirect issue for multiple sites pointing to our primary site although the intended affected sites are in their own server blocks.  If I disable the primary site, the others work as intended, so it seems something in the primary config is trumping the others.   Any help would be appreciated.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  access_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid 60s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
  open_file_cache_errors off;
  client_max_body_size 50M;
  client_body_buffer_size 1m;
  client_body_timeout 15;
  client_header_timeout 15;
  keepalive_timeout 2 2;
  send_timeout 15;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 120s;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
  reset_timedout_connection on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 100;
  fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1000m inactive=60m;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

This is the vhost conf that appears to be trumping other vhosts.  /etc/nginx/conf.d/site1.conf:

```
server {
        listen 10.10.10.1:80;
        listen 10.10.10.1:443 ssl;
        server_name  ^site1\.org$  ^www\.site1\.org$ ^old\.site1domain\.org$;
        ssl_certificate ...;
        ssl_certificate_key ...;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        keepalive_timeout 70;
        root  /var/www/vhosts/site1.org/httpdocs;
        index index.php;
        client_max_body_size 128M;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/site1.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                open_file_cache          max=4000 inactive=20s;
                open_file_cache_valid    30s;
                open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
                open_file_cache_errors   on;
        }
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
        if ($scheme != "https") {
                rewrite ^ https://site1.org$uri permanent;
        }
        if ($host != "site1.org") {
                rewrite ^ https://site1.org$uri permanent;
        }
        #wp-super-cache
        ....
        location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp)$ {
                expires max;
        }
```

}

Phew.  OK, here is an example of a different vhost config, which does not seem to be answering requests (instead, i get a 301 to the vhost above, with or without the redirects commented out).

/etc/nginx/conf.d/site2.conf:

```
server  {
    listen  10.10.10.1:80;
    server_name  ^sub1\.site2\.org$;
    allow  all;
    proxy_redirect  / http://10.10.10.1:6969;
    location  / {
            proxy_pass  http://10.10.10.1:6969;
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, this SSL proxy works as intended (on different IP):
/etc/nginx/conf.d/site3.conf:

```
server  {
        listen  10.10.10.2:443 ssl;
        server_name  ^sub3\.site1\.org$;
        ssl_certificate     ...;
        ssl_certificate_key ...;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        allow  all;
        proxy_redirect  / http://sub3.site1.org:80/;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass  http://sub3.site1.org:80/;
        }
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

Here is what I get when I attempt to connect to http://sub1.site2.org:

[c09 79] /etc/nginx/conf.d # wget {sub1.site2.url}
--2015-11-25 09:09:28--  {sub1.site2.url}
Resolving sub1.site2.org... 10.10.10.1
Connecting to sub1.site2.org|10.10.10.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: {site1.url} [following]

and so on...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `server_name` directives are all invalid so none of them match. So `nginx` uses the first `server` container as the default and processes all requests through that.

It then hits your `rewrite ^ https://site1.org$uri permanent;` conditional rewrite.

If you must use regex in your `server_name`s (although it's less efficient unless you really need it), you must prefix the name with `~`. Otherwise, just use the plain name.

```
server_name site1.org www.site1.org old.site1domain.org;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.